# adding mailto env variable through puppet?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, cron, puppet

```
cron {'Adding_environment_variable':
         environment     => "MAILTO=$email_list",
         user => 'root'
     }
```

Add the above code in puppet manifest,but it is not getting updated in crontab?
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

puppet cron type requires command, periodic attribute and user... and you are not providing any of it... Even if you want to override an existing crontab entry, you still need to provide those where the command and name should match with that of the existing one... Read the document here,

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#cron